# Create DTD for node with inner xml node and text

Tags: xml, dtd

I have pretty simple XML shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<message>
This is a message with some <bold>highlights</bold> in a text.
</message>
```

How can I create DTD to validate things inside message element? A mixture of node and text. This does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE message [
  <!ELEMENT message (#PCDATA, bold)>
  <!ELEMENT bold (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content) (both elements and text), you can't specify order (use `|` instead of `,`) and it has to be zero or more occurrences (`*`).

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE message [
<!ELEMENT message (#PCDATA|bold)*>
<!ELEMENT bold (#PCDATA)>
]>
<message>
    This is a message with some <bold>highlights</bold> in a text.
</message>
```